# How to expect Capybara::Expectation for a method

Tags: ruby, exception, capybara

```
def tiltle_finder(names)
  within 'table tbody tr:nth-child(1)' do
    page.should have_selector(
      'td:nth-child(10)',
      text: "#{names.label}"
    )
  end
end

it 'should find title' do
  expect{
    tiltle_finder(names)
  }.to raise_error(Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
```

but still trows that exception 
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def tiltle_finder(names)
  within 'table tbody tr:nth-child(1)' do
    page.find('td:nth-child(10)', text: "#{names.label}")
  end
end

it 'should find title' do
  expect{
    tiltle_finder(names)
  }.to raise_error(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
end
```

Solved as this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rescuing error you may just check that expectations are not met:

```
def have_title_finder(names)
  within 'table tbody tr:nth-child(1)' do
    have_selector(
      'td:nth-child(10)',
      text: "#{names.label}"
    )
  end
end

# ...
expect(page).not_to have_title_finder(names)
```

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(page).not_to title_finder(name)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Well, I've checked this code in sandbox and it works as expected